# In Word, how can I invert/reverse rows in a table?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2016

[image]

I need invert or reverse the entire rows in table overhead, so that:

- the two rows in each colour swap positions with the other of the same colour.
- the table descends from 4 to 1 (instead of 1 to 4 now in red numbering).

I clicked on the red numbering, then selected: Home ⟶ Sort ⟶ Sort by 'Column 2', Type: 'Number', 'Descending'. But nothing changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the red numbering a numbered list created by Word?

If so, Word will not recognize the numbers as numbers when sorting the column.

The numbered list will always run from 1 to 4. Only the words in it will change position.

If you want to sort the numbers from 4 to 1 (and keep them visible), you'll have to create a new column, add the numbers 1. to 4. (make sure they are not auto-formatted into a list), then sort for the new column.

Comment: Thanks. I answer your first question: I added the red numbering using the 'Numbering' feature in Word; so I instructed Word to create the numbering. Does this clarify?

Comment: Then you'll probably not be able to sort for the list (see above - a numbered list created by Word will not be counted when sorting). Try what ThunderFrame and I told you: Create a new column, type numbers in there, sort by those numbers. Just don't let Word auto-format the new column into a numbered list.

Comment: Thanks. Is there really no more efficient method than `type numbers in there, sort by those numbers` manually? I wish to verify this before I labour.

Comment: None that I know of, sorry. Numbers created using "numbering" feature will always stay in the same order. Question: Does the list have to be in created in Word? Excel could do exactly what you want here. It can auto-number columns without formatting them into the numbered format).

Answer (score 4):

You need to sort on a column that has values that will sort in the order you want. So, either temporarily add a column, (or prefix each of the values in one of your current columns) with values, 4,3,2,1, then sort on that column in ascending order.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to type the numbers manually, you can number an extra first column automatically, copy the numbers, delete the numbering, and paste "only text" on top of the first column. That way, you've avoided autonumbering, and ended up with the numbered columns anyway. I was able to then sort in a descending way with it.